# Webkit absolutely positioned buttons stretch all the way across

Tags: css, firefox, button, webkit

The following code works differently in Firefox and Webkit (Safari/Chrome) and should not. From what I understand, Firefox is rendering it correctly. How can I make Webkit render it the same?

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style type="text/css">
.frell {
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="container">
      <button class="frell">Test</button>
    </div>
  <body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably inheriting either it's parent's width or getting display:block. What does the Chrome developer tools say? I'd either specify a width (% or px) or display:inline (possibly inline-block)

Comment: Problem is, this is a class that's supposed to be used on any button anywhere (not actually named frell, that was isolating the issue). If I specify a width, I have fixed-width buttons. NOT what I want here.

display: inline doesn't do anything different.

Comment: Acording to the Safari and Chrome inspectors: Computed style is:display: block;
.frell - inline
XXX input, textarea, keygen, select, button, isindex - inline-block user agent stylesheet XXX

This indicates to me that it gets the inline style, and then totally ignores it.

Answer (score 0):

Firefox is rendering it incorrectly, webkit is rendering it correctly.  To make firefox behave, you need to add `width: 100%` to the class, even then, that won't work in all cases, but it will be closer.

Absolutely positioning an item and specifying both left and right should make the item become the necessary width to fill the space between them.  For a simple test, here is a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/c3EeF/2/ that shows what happens when you apply the same class to both the button and div tags.  Firefox misbehaves when using the button, and I have been unable to find any setting that makes it work 100% correctly.

Comment: Firefox is rendering it the way it seems it should. I don't want to add width: 100% to the class because I do not want it width: 100%; I want it width unspecified so that the button is the size of the contents + padding and border. I have margin: auto set and have specified it as an inline and inline block both and in both cases the display is actually discarded and totally ignored. (Note, I also want this to be simple to apply as a class without having to muck about with a container element making the page more complex unnecessarily)

Comment: If you want the button to be the size of the contents+padding+border, then remove `left:0;right:0` because that is supposed to stretch the button to be the entire width of the closest parent container that isn't positioned statically (which firefox is doing incorrectly).  If you arn't using left/right, then I wonder why you are positioning it absolutely.  Additionally, margin:auto will only center items that are `display:block`.  If all you want is the button to be centered, then remove all the other styles and just use `margin:auto;`